# How to prevent a session

Tags: php, session

When navigating to the Facebook social network, I see that I can open 2 accounts (1 in Firefox and the other in Internet Explorer), or maybe multiple accounts. This is not so good knowing that the Facebook policy allows only to open a session at the same time.

When starting a session, how to prevent the same session (considering the session name `$_SESSION['user']`) from being re-opened in another browser (Internet Explorer/Safari/Opera...)?

Otherwise, how can I know (with PHP) that a certain session is open in all browsers to prevent the session to be open twice?

Comment: Store the user's IP and if they have a session or not, then check the IP?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to have a `LoggedIn` boolean flag in your users table.

Comment: @Rocket , thank you +1, I've never thought of that, but the IP adress seems more difficult to have than Ben's answer , @Ben, this is a useful way (I will use it +1) : thank you all!

Comment: @Rocket - that won't prevent an account from logging into the same account from two different IPs.  @Ben - what if somebody logs in from and goes to work and tries to login there? They'll be forced to wait until that flag is cleared.  Basically they'll be locked out of the account.  IMHO, @Pradeep's method would work best.  I've added an explanation of how it works.  Please consider using this, as it is immune to the two issues with the methods posted above.

Comment: @Colin but it will prevent indeed , one IP from opening the same account from different browsers, and this exacly meets my needs

Comment: @Colin , "what if somebody logs in from and goes to work and tries to login there?" , I've thought of this , then an ajax verification every 5 minutes will clear the field if the currentTime-LogTime=5min (LogTime is in user table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$token = hash('sha256', rand() . microtime() . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) // rand as possible
$_SERVER['user'] = $token;
```

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand this code very well,is it about a server variable?

Comment: Okey, creating a server variable that will take the username, right?

Comment: I've used this approach before.  Basically when the user logs in, create a server variable called "user_" + their username (ex: "user_simotaqi".  This has a value based on, among other things, the login time.  Also store this in the user's session.  On each page load, make sure they match.

Comment: When the user creates a second session, the SERVER variable will be different so you'd basically invalidate that first user's session.  Consider using a helpful error message so the first user understand why they were kicked out.

Comment: And if you need to kick somebody out for whatever reason, you simply change that SERVER variable to something else and the user's session will be terminated on the next page load, when the site realizes the two tokens don't match.

Comment: @Colin this is the best way (cuz it saves me creating new fields in my table for the loginID or for IPs) thank you! +1

Comment: @Colin does facebook using this approach to know if someone is logged in?

Comment: @Colin and a last question,if this server variable = "user1", and another user tries to login from a second IP (say "user2") does this server variable="user2" or simply the server creates a second variable server["user2"] for this user

Comment: I'm not sure if Facebook uses this exact method, but I'm sure its very similar.  And yes, each user has a separate server variable.  The basic idea is that the server and session variables will always match unless that user account is logged in again, in which case the server variable will change to something else.

Comment: Also, please note you don't have to use SERVER variables, although they are pretty easy.  The token can instead be stored in Memcache or MySQL if it makes sense for you (you probably won't need to unless the website becomes insanely popular and you need to track tens of thousands of users).  Hope that helps! Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *preventing* a new session from being opened in a new browser if there is already an open session elsewhere, consider *invalidating* any existing sessions to that user account when a new Sign In occurs. This will minimise user frustration, and is simple to implement.

Comment: thank you for recalling me of this issue, I will check in the other browser if the user database field (logedIn)already = yes then I will pass this user ID to the session, thank you +1

Comment: @Simo - But that seems unreliable. I would simply kill/clear all session data (for that particular user) when a login happens, and create new session data for the latest login.

Comment: but if you kill/clear all session data for a user when he logs in,and create new session data, this session will be only open in the browser last used in login

Comment: @Simo - true. You have to find all existing session files linked to that particular user, and remove them prior to creating the new session.

Comment: I completely agree. Pradeep's code accomplishes uses this idea.