# Server Variable is not recognizable in other pages

Tags: php, apache, server-variables

I have this code in the login.php file :

```
 //save user data 
  $token=$user->getId().'_'.hash('sha256',$user->getUsername().microtime());
  $name='fsusr_'.$user->getUsername();

  //set session and server variables
  $_SESSION[$name]=$token;   //set session variable
  $_SERVER[$name]=$token;    //set server variable
```

and in the page_init.php , just after login process, I want to retrieve the server and session variables so that I can compare them , and decide what to do next:

I have this on line 8 :

```
 echo $_SERVER[$name];
```

In fact , the problem is that the other page sends me this error in this very line:

Undefined index: fsusr_smoootk in ... on line 8.

When I make an print_r($_SERVER) in login.php , I see the array containing the $_SERVER[$name] variable... But when doing the same in the other page, I see that it no more contains that variable.

I know that it did not save the server variable to the other page, But I don't know why?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you set a value to `$_SERVER`, it doesn't mean you can access it on another page. That's why `$_SESSION` exists, to persist data between different calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $_SERVER variable is meant for server information. You should assign your own variables into $_SESSION.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: But look here to know what I'm trying to do with the server variable :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431294/how-to-prevent-a-session

Comment: What are you trying to do? Determine if one user connected to your website from two different browsers? Point is, you can't.

Comment: When I asked that question before, they told me to create a server variable with the same name as the session variable..and compare them in each page load..

Comment: Actually, the server variable is set in login.php..and I can display it and read it there, and it's contained in $_SERVER array too...But not in the second page.

Comment: @SimoTAQI - I read the other question and you're getting answers that aren't helping your cause. Facebook probably doesn't allow 2 accounts to the same person. That has nothing to do with actual session that implies the current visit to the website. Behind 1 IP, you can have an entire network, such as a university or something similar - therefore you can't identify a single user by their IP. You can attempt to identify them using info provided by their browser, which is what everyone do on the web - but that info **can be modified by the user whenever they want**.

Comment: so , you say that there's no way to prevent connecting to the same account from two machines? right?

But what about creating two session variables one changing every login process, and get compared after every page load?

Comment: Actually,Nope , it won't work ..this 2 sessions stuff..thank you N.B and +1 :))

Answer (score 1):

try this `$_SESSION['name'] = $token`

you are saving data in session and echoing $_SERVER... nice man !

Comment: the question is : $name is dynamically generated , it's not static

Comment: $_SERVER is php's global array,#

Comment: the problem is with the $_SERVER variable I created in login.php... not with the $_SESSION variable..

$_SERVER is just to see if the server variable is still in the array

Comment: buddy $_SERVER is php's global array, it is constant, you can not use this array to hold any of your data, you only need to use $_SEESION

Comment: I don't really know, I've asked this question many times before and the answer was really "Yes"

Comment: now you know it, be known my friend, thre is huge difference b/w $_SERVER and $_SESSION, if my answer is not acceptable then at least it's worthy to vote :-)

Comment: it's acceptable of course, I know $_SERVER is different from $_SESSION.. But you can see here , why Am I using $_SERVER variables now  stackoverflow.com/questions/4431294/how-to-prevent-a-session

Comment: yes you right, but there is no way to use $_SERVER to hold personalized data,

Comment: I agree with you, it seems that I was blinded somewhere else hhhhhhh